# Combinatorics Question from SUMaC 2020

Tags: combinatorics

Pyramids are colored according to the following rules: (1) Each block can be red, gold,
or black, and (2) All 3-block units composed of one block on top of two others must
either all be the same color or all be different colors.

How many ways are there to color a 7-pyramid

Comment: There are 9 ways to colour a 2-pyramid. You can probably use a recursive argument to add the bottom row each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a row of any pyramid, we see that the row above it is completely fixed by the colouring restriction: if two adjacent blocks are different (same), the block above them must be the third (same) colour. So the number of $n$-pyramids is the same as the number of ways to colour the unrestricted bottom row of $n$ blocks, i.e. $3^n$. The answer to the specific question is $3^7=2187$.